# Files disappearing from Time Machine folder after backup

Tags: server, samba, backup, mac

I've got quite delicate problem with macOS backups over SMB. I did set-up Time Machine server on Ubuntu Server 20.04 with SMB. When the server start/restart, everything works fine, I can see Time Machine server on all my Macs and I can access it's previous backups and even making backup works perfect. However after some time (I can't figure out what is the trigger) all files from Time Machine disk disappear (when I am trying to access them from macOS) and every backup fails with error:

> **Time Machine couldn’t complete the backup to “data-server.local”**
> *The network backup disk does not support the required capabilities.*

When I log into the server (over SSH to the Ubuntu Server) and `ls` the Time Machine folder, it's completely empty. Restarting SMB and Avahi services doesn't help. When I reboot the whole OS however, everything is back (and new backup made before failure is there) and all Macs can perform the backup without any issues again.

As I said, I cannot find the trigger. Sometimes it does happen after two hours, sometimes after a day, but never after longer period of time. It almost looks like it does happen after a single backup, but I have three Macs on the network and all of them manage to make a full backup without a disruption, every single one in different time (all of them has the same user account and logging to server with same credentials).

I am completely lost here as I cannot logically explain this behaviour.

I am providing SMB config if it does help:

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = %h
   server role = standalone server
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = no

[TimeMachine]
   comment = Time Machine
   path = /media/TimeMachine
   browseable = yes
   writeable = yes
   read only = no
   force create mode = 0600
   force directory mode = 2770
   spotlight = yes
   vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr
   durable handles = yes
   kernel oplocks = no
   kernel share modes = no
   posix locking = no
   ea support = yes
   inherit acls = yes
   fruit:aapl = yes
   fruit:time machine = yes
   fruit:model = MacPro
   fruit:advertise_fullsync = true
   valid users = davedavee @sadmin
   socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_RCVBUF=524288 SO_SNDBUF=524288
```

**edit**

Just came on my mind: One possibility could be disk sleep function. Since the OS is server edition, it shouldn't be the case, but sounds pretty reasonable. The disk is connected over USB driver by the way (if it does matter). If it is the "drive sleep mode" option, how can I check its settings and what is correct setup? I know I can Google it or read some man page, but like I said, it just came on my mind and the question is already asked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I have sorted this out. It looks like the driver of the external driver board does fail after some time (the harddrive used for TimeMachine was connected over external driver card in PCI slot). I've connected the disk over USB 3.0 > SATA driver into the motherboards USB 3.0 port and it is working fine so far.

I will post updates if there will be other issues, but only if they will be. Otherwise sorted out.

Comment: Ok, so when the problem is solved, another raised. I have to find out whats going on with the PCI driver :/